# Query error while inserting into Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just trying to insert some variables into a DB.  The connection works but I keep getting a query error.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="process-step1.php" method="post">

    <div id="fromDiv" class="clearfix">
        <h4>Your Name</h4>
        <input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="" />
        <h4>Your E-mail</h4>
        <input type="text" name="fromemail" id="fromemail" value="" />
    </div>

    <div id="toDiv" class="clearfix">
        <h4>Recipient Name</h4>
        <input type="text" name="to" id="to" value="" />
        <h4>Recipient E-mail</h4>
        <input type="text" name="toemail" id="toemail" value="" />
    </div>

    <div id="messageDiv" class="clearfix">
        <h4>Message</h4>
        <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div id="submitDiv" class="clearfix">
        <input type="submit" value="Preview my Card" name="submit" id="submit" />
    </div>

</form>
```

Here is the PHP Process:

```
$from = mysql_escape_string($_POST['from']);
$fromemail = mysql_escape_string($_POST['fromemail']);
$to = mysql_escape_string($_POST['to']);
$toemail = mysql_escape_string($_POST['toemail']);
$message = mysql_escape_string($_POST['message']);

$query = "INSERT INTO cards (fromemail, from, to, toemail, message, stamp) VALUES ('$fromemail', '$from', '$to', '$toemail', '$message', 'now()' )";
$results = mysql_query($query);
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the [reserved](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) word - `To` and `From`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cards (fromemail, `from`, `to`, toemail, message, stamp) VALUES 
           ('$fromemail', '$from', '$to', '$toemail', '$message', 'now()' )";
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I have changed the field/variable names and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cards (fromemail, from, to, toemail, message, stamp) VALUES ('".$fromemail."', '".$from."', '".$to."', '".$toemail."', '".$message."', '".now()' )";
```